# unable to add specific date and time to UserNotifications in swift

Tags: swift, datepicker, calendar, uilocalnotification

I am getting Date and time from Datepicker to textfield.. that date and time i need to set notification.. i have added `requestAuthorization` in app delegate

**notification code:** i have tried to give datepicker date to **dateComponents**  then `yourFireDate` time not coming correctly i mean

**if i give date and time `8/25/20, 1:03 PM` then yourFireDate always coming like `2020-08-24 18:30:00 +0000`** and remainder also not coming

```
 func displayReminderLocalNotification(body: String) {
    
    components = dtPicker.calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: dtPicker.date)
    day = components?.day
     month = components?.month
     year = components?.year
     hrs = components?.hour
    mins = components?.minute
    
    guard let yourFireDate = Calendar.current.date(from: components!) else { return }
    
    print("ihwdeiwqjheiq \(yourFireDate)")
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey:
                "Your notification title", arguments: nil)
    content.body = body
    content.categoryIdentifier = "Your notification category"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
    content.badge = 1

     let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents(Set(arrayLiteral: Calendar.Component.year, Calendar.Component.month, Calendar.Component.day, Calendar.Component.hour, Calendar.Component.minute), from: yourFireDate)
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "notification identifier", content: content, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}
```

like this i am using date picker:

```
 let dateFormatter       = DateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
  dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
  let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: dtPicker.date)

   dateLabel.text = strDate
```

How to set notification on particular date and time coming from datepicker to textfield. please help me with code

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems OK.

How are you testing the notification (reminder)? if you just manually change your device date to the desired date, but more than 15 minutes away from the exact time -> you won't see a notification! Try to jump to a minute **before** the expected notification time and then move to the next minute (or wait:)). This may be tricky if you don't set hour/minute so it becomes 00:00.

Also, if you want to be sure, you can set `DateComponents` explicitly:

```
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.year = ...
dateComponents.month = ...
dateComponents.day = ...
dateComponents.hour = ...
dateComponents.minute = ...
```

Comment: thank you, i have added hours and minutes.. but here `yourFireDate` coming wrongly.. why

Comment: here datepicker date not properly adding to calender

Comment: i am calling `displayReminderLocalNotification(body: "remainder for an event on \(Fromdate!) \(FromTime!)` like this in API service

Comment: `body` is a string and you just set it to the content, so it doesn't really matter. Is there a chance your UIDatePicker timezone or locale is not what you expect?